# Are the special member functions always declared?

Tags: c++, c++11

In §12 of the standard every special member function has a set of rules which cause it to be `implicitly declared as defaulted` and another set of rules which cause `a defaulted [special member function to be] defined as deleted`.

This makes it seem (to me) that there are 3 potential states when no user-declared version is present for special member functions: declared and defined (`defaulted`), declared and undefined (`deleted`), and undeclared. Is this accurate? If so, what point is there as opposed to cutting out the 'undeclared' option?

<sub>* `declared as defaulted` seems like a mistake, shouldn't it be "defined" as defaulted?</sub>

Comment: @downvoter Why? Let me know so I can fix it.

Comment: I only have N3290 to read right now and the relevant place is 8.4.2 and 8.4.3. Are you referring to a draft or the final released standard?

Comment: Chapter 12 Special member functions [special]. Is in n3242

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between a deleted constructor and an implicitly undeclared constructor is that the deleted constructor participates in overload resolution, whereas the constructor that doesn't exist, doesn't participate in overload resolution.

Example:

This class is default constructible.  The compiler does not implicitly declare a defaulted constructor for it.

```
struct A
{
    template <class ...T>
    A(T...) {}
};

int main()
{
    A a;  // ok
}
```

If the compiler did declare a default constructor for it, and if that default constructor was defined as deleted, then `A` would not be default constructible.  That can be simulated with:

```
struct A
{
    A() = delete;  // pretend the compiler implicitly declared and defined this

    template <class ...T>
    A(T...) {}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
}

error: call to deleted constructor of 'A'
    A a;
      ^
```

Similar problems appear with the move constructor.  If the compiler decides to implicitly declare it and define it as deleted, then one can not construct such a class from an rvalue, even if it has a viable copy constructor:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    A();
    A(const A&);
    A(A&&) = delete;  // pretend compiler declared and defined
};

int main()
{
    A a = std::declval<A>();
}

error: call to deleted constructor of 'A'
    A a = std::declval<A>();
      ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But if the compiler **does not** implicitly declare a deleted move constructor, then things just work:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    A();
    A(const A&);
};

int main()
{
    A a = std::declval<A>();  // ok
}
```

Indeed, if the compiler *did* implicitly declare a deleted move constructor for `A`, there would be a awful lot of broken C++98/03 code when recompiled in C++11! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I not sure I agree with your summary:

There are basically three states: `User Defined`, `Deleted` or `Compiler Generated`

- declared and defined

  - This means the user has explicitly declared them in the class and provided definitions.
- declared and deleted

  - This means the user has explicitly declared them as deleted (ie they are not available).
- undeclared

  - The user has not provided a declaration (and thus can not provide a definition).
    In this case the the compiler will generate a version of the method.

Comment: And the old way of doing `declared and deleted`: `declared but not defined` - the user has explicitly declared them in the class and but hasn't provided definitions.

Comment: @dalle: That's not really a part of the language; that is just a linker error waiting to happen. But yes `declared private and not defined` is the C++03 equivalent of `declared and deleted` from C++11. The C++11 way is neater as you don't need to add an extra comment saying that it is deliberately not defined (please do not add a definition). And since it is part of the language can get flagged as an error much quicker.

Comment: @LokiAstari The 3 states I was questioning are "potential states when no user-declared version is present", they all fall under your last state.