# ambiguous overload with deleted move constructor

Tags: c++, g++

g++ 4.6.3 and 4.7.2 fail to compile the following code (in c++0x mode) if BREAK
is defined.

```
template<class T> struct Test {
    Test(T&) {}
#ifdef BREAK
    Test(T&&) = delete;
#endif
};

void func(Test<int> const&) {}
void func(Test<double> const&) {}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    func(x);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is

```
error: call of overloaded 'func(int&)' is ambiguous
```

while clang 3.2 RC2 and VC11 (if I replace `Test(T&&) = delete;` with `private: Test(T&&);`) accept the code.

I can't see where that should be ambiguous.

Is this a g++ issue? (I don't know what to search for in the gcc bug list...)

Comment: FWIW, `= delete`d functions are not removed from overload resolution. It only means that if overload resolution picks them, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Yes, but it's `func` which is ambiguous. `Test` in the original code is a `std::reference_wrapper` and the `delete`d constructor is to prevent reference to temporaries, IIUC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deleted constructors participate in overload resolution ([Are the special member functions always declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628094/are-the-special-member-functions-always-declared)); this is necessary so that one can use deleted constructors to prevent conversions (excerpted from 8.4.3p3):

```
struct onlydouble {
  onlydouble(std::intmax_t) = delete;
  onlydouble(double);
};
```

Enforcement of function deletion comes very late in the compilation process, after overload resolution (8.4.3p2) and so overload resolution cannot distinguish between constructors on the basis of deletion.  gcc is correct and clang and VC11 are incorrect.

Note that the ambiguity is in the function call expression `func(x)`, where the argument `x` is an lvalue of type `int` and the id `func` denotes an overload set with parameter types in the first (only) parameter of `const Test<int> &` and `const Test<double> &`; the available conversion sequences then are:

1. `int` lvalue; `int &`; `Test<int>` temporary; `const Test<int> &`,
2. `int` lvalue; `int` rvalue; `double` rvalue; `double &&`; `Test<double>` temporary; `const Test<double> &`.

The two sequences are user-defined conversion sequences of equal rank, and so are ambiguous.  The fact that the constructor `Test<double>::Test(double &&)` is deleted is irrelevant at this stage.

Comment: Hm... I don't see where this is relevant here. I am calling `func` with an lvalue-reference to an `int` (g++ tells me). Now `Test<int>` is implicitly constructible from an `int&`, while `Test<double>` is not. So the only viable overload is `func(Test<int> const&)`, isn't it?

Comment: @Alex `Test<double>` is implicitly constructible from an `int` via arithmetic conversion to `double` and then rvalue reference binding.

Comment: I thought I understood your answer, so I have submitted a [bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=14505). But it seems it's not that clear...

Comment: @Alex I've updated that bug report with my reasoning; DR 1164 doesn't apply because this bug obtains even in the absence of templates.

Answer (score 1):

There is open bug in GCC: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54425.

CLANG is correct, GCC needs to fix this.

Comment: I don't think this is the same problem... In the bug report, the first `f` matches with `T = int` and the second `f` matches with `T = int&` and therefore the call to `f`is ambiguous. But in the problem above no template argument deduction is involved.

Comment: There is defect report, it should not be ambigues -- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1164

Comment: You might be right... I have submitted a [bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=14505). Maybe you want to have a look?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I don't have anything add to what Kaelyn Uhrain said.  CLANG have correct behavior. Daniel Krügler (gcc developer) confirmed  that this is a bug in GCC.