# boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable analog for move constructor/assignment

Tags: c++, boost

One can quickly make a type noncopyable by inheriting `boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable`. Is there anything similar for preventing a type from being moveable?

Comment: You may be able to do this by making the move constructor private.  Why would you need to do this, though?

Comment: @Taywee: To guarantee some classes in my program cannot possibly be used in an improper way. These classes have a fairly complicated system of "ownership relations", which would be completely broken if I allowed move semantics.

Comment: I see.  Keep in mind that many container types internally use move construction, like vectors, so those will also be off-limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a copy constructor but not a move constructor, no move constructor will be generated. Same for assignment. So:

```
struct not_movable {
    not_movable(const not_movable&) = default;
    not_movable& operator=(const not_movable&) = default;
};
```

Comment: In c++11 you may also explicitly delete the move constructor: `not_movable(const not_movable&&) = delete;`

Comment: Obviously, I didn't intend for the const to be there:  `not_movable(not_movable&&) = delete;`

Comment: I cannot make a (meaningful) copy constructor/assignment pair. My classes already have noncopyable members (e.g., a `std::map<std::size_t, std::fstream>`), and that is why I only care about making it nonmoveable.

Comment: In that case, either explicit move constructor deletion or a private move constructor should be sufficient.

Comment: @Taywee - do **not** delete the move constructor. You'll get **very** surprising results. `not_movable f(); not_movable nm = f();` That last statement is an error; it does **not** use the copy constructor, but tries to use the deleted move constructor.

Comment: @EduardoLeón - then simply declaring but not defining the copy constructor, just as Boost's `noncopyable` does, will take care of things. Declaring the copy constructor suppresses the compiler-generated move constructor.

Comment: @Pete - You are correct.  Thank you for informing me.  I wasn't aware of the potentially disastrous effects of constructor deletion.  More info:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/13703186/1362309 - http://stackoverflow.com/q/14640366/1362309 - http://stackoverflow.com/q/16703798/1362309

Comment: @Taywee - it's high on my list because I just came across it in some code that I wrote. The interaction between `= delete` and move constructors is not intuitive.