# Return a named object of a class from a function (by value ) and implicit move rule?

Tags: c++

I have a problem  with understanding what happens when you return an object of a class ( Not a specific class ) form a function ( pass by value )
in this code :
**EXAMPLE 1**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class test {
public:
    test(int y) {
        printf(" test(int y)\n");
    }
    test() {
        printf(" test()\n");
    }
    test( const test& z) {
        printf(" test( const test&z)\n");
    }
    test(test&& s)noexcept{
            printf(" test(test&& s)\n");          
    }
    test& operator=(test e) {
        printf(" test& operator=( test e)\n");
        return *this;
    }
};
test Some_thing() {
    test i;
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    Some_thing();
    return 0;
}
```

The Output :

```
 test()
 test(test&& s)
```

The previous Output makes me understand that in the function ( Some_thing ( ) ) Scope there are two objects are created . the first one is an lvalue object which we create it in the first line in the function ( Some_thing ( ) ) and we give it a name ( i ) So the constructor  `test ( )`  is called.
And the second one is an rvalue object So the constructor  `test ( test&& s )`  is called.

But when i deleted this constructor   `test(test&& s)noexcept`  and changed this constructor

`test( const test& z)`

into

```
test( test& z)
```

and run the code again :

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class test {
public:
    test(int y) {
        printf(" test(int y)\n");
    }
    test() {
        printf(" test()\n");
    }
    test( test& z) {
        printf(" test( test&z)\n");
    }
    test& operator=(test e) {
        printf(" test& operator=( test e)\n");
        return *this;
    }
};
test Some_thing() {
    test i;
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    Some_thing();
    return 0;
}
```

The Output :

```
 test()
 test( test&z)
```

While I expected that this code will not compile because there is no constructor takes  `test&&`  or  `const test&` as a parameter

and when i tried to add one line to the previous code which is `test(test&& z) = delete`

**EXAMPLE 3**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class test {
public:
    test(test&& z) = delete;
    test(int y) {
        printf(" test(int y)\n");
    }
    test() {
        printf(" test()\n");
    }
    test( const test& z) {
        printf(" test( test&z)\n");
    }
    test& operator=(test e) {
        printf(" test& operator=( test e)\n");
        return *this;
    }
};
test Some_thing() {
    test i;
    return i;
}
int main()
{
  Some_thing();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile it but it does not compile and it does not run

So how does EXAMPLE 2 compile and run ?????? and how can the constructor `test( test&z)` be used instead of
`test(test&& z)` ??????

( I mean `test( test&z)` is not `test( const test&z)`  So `test( test&z)`  can not be used instead of  `test(test&& z)` )

edit :
this code compiles and runs :
**EXAMPLE 4**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class test {
public:
    test(test&& z) = delete;
    test(int y) {
        printf(" test(int y)\n");
    }
    test() {
        printf(" test()\n");
    }
    test(const test& z) {
        printf(" test( test&z)\n");
    }
    test& operator=(test e) {
        printf(" test& operator=( test e)\n");
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    test u;
    test r(u);
    return 0;
}
```

The Output :

```
 test()
 test( test&z)
```

Comment: Object slicing happens. Never do this.

Comment: What is Object slicing ????? and when does it happen in my examples ????  
@user207421

Comment: It depends. In older C++ standards (before C++17) the semantics of returning by value was returning a copy to the caller.   BUT, those standards *also* explicitly permitted (but did not require) the compiler to elide (omit) the copies of objects in some cases (e.g. if the only way to check a copy had occurred was by tracking calls of constructors and destructors) and some compilers (with relevant optimisation settings) implemented a return value optimisation to elide copies in some situations and some didn't.    From C++17, copy elision became mandatory in several circumstances.

Comment: @user207421 How is object slicing happening? There's no inheritance here.

Comment: I think the key misunderstanding for example 2 is that you think a copy constructor must use `const`, but that is not true.  The "class.copy" section of the C++ standard explicitly says a constructor like `test(test&)` is a copy constructor.

Comment: my question is  : How can a value be taken as an rvlaue (test&& ) and an lvalue ( test& ) ?????
@David Grayson

Comment: Since this is the `return` statement, the object in question is about to be destroyed, so it's fine to just treat it as an rvalue, since it won't be used later.  Are you looking for a specific reference ot the C++ standard?   I think Anoop Rana's answer covers that.

Comment: Okay how can an rvalue be taken by a constructor which takes an lvalue ?
@David Grayson

Comment: The object can be treated as an rvalue or an lvalue so it can go into either constructor, as explained in Anoop's answer.  Remember the object is about to be destroyed, so it's OK if we move it (potentially putting it into a different state) or just copy it.  Either way it will get destroyed later.  Is there a specific thing you're worried about?

Comment: when you say  (potentially putting it into a different state) you mean make it rvalue
and copy it as rvalue  , right? 
and when you say ( or just copy it. ) you mean copy it as it is ( lvalue ) , right ?
@ David Grayson

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: the explanations of the two sentences ( (potentially putting it into a different state) , ( or just copy it. ) ) is right ?
@David Grayson

Comment: Yes, that is right, and I already said it is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tldr;**

`i` is move-eligible and so considered an *xvalue* as per [prim.id.unequal](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#prim.id.unqual-3.sentence-6). Thus, the move ctor can be used here.

> **The expression is an xvalue if it is move-eligible** (see below); an lvalue if the entity is a function, variable, structured binding, data member, or template parameter object; and a prvalue otherwise ([basic.lval]); it is a bit-field if the identifier designates a bit-field.

---

The same can be seen from [Automatic move from local variables and parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Notes):

> If expression is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names a variable whose type is either
>
> - a non-volatile object type or
> - a non-volatile rvalue reference to object type (since C++20)
>
> and that **variable is declared**
>
> - **in the body** or
> - as a parameter of
>
>   the innermost enclosing function or lambda expression,
>
> then overload resolution to select the constructor to use for initialization of the returned value or, for co_return, to select the overload of promise.return_value() (since C++20) is **performed twice**:
>
> - first **as if expression were an rvalue expression** (thus it **may select the move constructor**), and
>
> > - **if the first overload resolution failed** or
>
> > - it succeeded, but did not select the move constructor (formally, the first parameter of the selected constructor was not an rvalue reference to the (possibly cv-qualified) type of expression) (until C++20)
>
> - then overload resolution is **performed as usual, with expression considered as an lvalue** (so it may select the **copy constructor**).

Now, lets apply this to your code snippet on case by case basis.

##### Example 1

In this case, as the move ctor is available and viable, the condition *"first as if expression were an rvalue expression"* is satisfied and hence the move ctor is selected we get the mentioned output.

```
class test {
public:
    test(int y) {
        printf(" test(int y)\n");
    }
    test() {
        printf(" test()\n");
    }
    test( const test& z) {
        printf(" test( const test&z)\n");
    }
    test(test&& s)noexcept{
            printf(" test(test&& s)\n");          
    }
    test& operator=(test e) {
        printf(" test& operator=( test e)\n");
        return *this;
    }
};
test Some_thing() {
    test i;
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    Some_thing();
    return 0;
}
```

---

##### Example 2

In this case, since you've provided the copy ctor `test::test( test&)`, the compiler will not synthesize a move ctor for us. Note that not having a synthesized move ctor is different from having a deleted move ctor. Thus the condition *"if the first overload resolution failed"* is satisfied(because there is no move ctor) and the overload resolution is then performed for the second time which will now select the provided copy ctor and hence the mentioned output.

```
class test {
public:
    test(int y) {
        printf(" test(int y)\n");
    }
    test() {
        printf(" test()\n");
    }
    test( test& z) {
        printf(" test( test&z)\n");
    }
    test& operator=(test e) {
        printf(" test& operator=( test e)\n");
        return *this;
    }
};
test Some_thing() {
    test i;
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    Some_thing();
    return 0;
}
```

---

##### Example 3

In this case, you've explicitly **deleted** the move ctor. That is, your intent is that if someone tried to use the move ctor, then it should fail. So here, when the overload resolution happens for the first time, the move ctor is selected but since you've explicitly marked it as deleted fails immediately and hence the error.

```
class test {
public:
    test(test&& z) = delete;
    test(int y) {
        printf(" test(int y)\n");
    }
    test() {
        printf(" test()\n");
    }
    test( const test& z) {
        printf(" test( test&z)\n");
    }
    test& operator=(test e) {
        printf(" test& operator=( test e)\n");
        return *this;
    }
};
test Some_thing() {
    test i;
    return i;
}
int main()
{
  Some_thing();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: first thank you very much for answering my question . and I have one more question when I try to compile the code ( EXAMPLE 1 ) using a different compiler ( a C++14 compiler ) and
  ` test(test&& s)` was not appeared . That is due to Copy elision , right ?
 ( I used in my question a C++98 compiler )
@Anoop Rana

Comment: @f877576 Yes, it is due to [copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). You can even confirm this by providing the `-fno-elide-constructors` flag to the compiler. For example when you provide this `-fno-elide-constructors` flag you'll get the output `test()
 test(test&& s)`. [Demo with flag](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cHBbd3bhOPK9hrTp). And if you don't provide this flag, the compilers are allowed to elide copy/move construction. [Demo without flag](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kt1YIAGl1DJi9Pjg). And you're welcome.

Comment: Is ( ctor ) an abbreviation of  the word ( constructor ) ? @Anoop Rana

Comment: @f877576 Yes "ctor" stands for constructor while "dtor" stands for destructor.

Comment: What is the meaning of  ( a synthesize move constructor ) ?
@Anoop Rana

Comment: @f877576 Under some conditions, the compiler will automatically/implictly declare the move ctor for us. This compiler generated move ctor is called *synthesized move ctor*. See [Implicitly-declared move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-declared_move_constructor) for more details. For example, you might already know that under certain conditions the compiler will automatically generate a default ctor. In that case, we say that compiler generated default ctor as *synthesized default ctor*.

Comment: @f877576 Also refer to [what is a synthesized constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322728/what-is-a-synthesized-constructor).

Comment: I am sorry but I did not know that @Anoop Rana

Comment: @f877576 It's okay. I suspected that you weren't aware of  this feature of Stackoverflow:)

Comment: So any constructor I do not write it ( the compiler automatically/implictly declares it )  is a synthesize constructor ???? @Anoop Rana

Comment: @f877576 The compiler will generate a particular ctor under some condition(specified by the standard c++). Also, the word "synthesized" in the context that we're talking means "automatically created". So whatever ctor is automatically generated by the compiler we call that ctor a *"synthesized ctor"*.