# Question about copy constructor in return value

Tags: c++, c++17, move-semantics, lvalue

This is a code test from [this](https://shaharmike.com/cpp/rvo/).
I reproduced some of them as below:

```
//struct definition. All kinds of prints
struct Snitch {   // Note: All methods have side effects
  Snitch() { cout << "c'tor" << endl; }
  ~Snitch() { cout << "d'tor" << endl; }

  Snitch(const Snitch&) { cout << "copy c'tor" << endl; }
  Snitch(Snitch&&) { cout << "move c'tor" << endl; }

  Snitch& operator=(const Snitch&) {
    cout << "copy assignment" << endl;
    return *this;
  }

  Snitch& operator=(Snitch&&) {
    cout << "move assignment" << endl;
    return *this;
  }
};
//end struct def

Snitch ReturnObj() {
  Snitch snit;
  cout<< "before return ReturnObj" << endl;
  return snit;  
}

int main() { 
  Snitch snitchobj1 = ReturnObj();  
  cout<< "end main" << endl;
}
```

I disabled RVO as the author:  **g++ -fno-elide-constructors -o rvo.exe .\rvo_or_not.cpp**
and run **rvo.exe** in order to find what exactly happens.

I got:

```
c'tor
before return ReturnObj
move c'tor //I didn't know why this is move c'tor instead of copy c'tor
d'tor
move c'tor
d'tor
end main
d'tor
```

The first printing of move c'tor is unexpected for me. The line "Snitch snit;" in function defines a local lvalue **snit** . So when returned, the copy construtor should be called to initialize the temporary object? Am I right? Or it's an xvalue actually not a lvalue?

Comment: See the detailed explanation given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898998/return-a-named-object-of-a-class-from-a-function-by-value-and-implicit-move-r/71934476#71934476) of the dupe: [Return a named object of a class from a function (by value ) and implicit move rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898998/return-a-named-object-of-a-class-from-a-function-by-value-and-implicit-move-r)

Comment: Note that the referred question/answer is a bit outdated; it says about the double lookup while overloading is resolved. However, the newer standards no longer do this. Instead, they say that the value category of `snit` in `return snit;` is _xvalue_. See: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#prim.id.unqual-3.sentence-6.

Comment: @DanielLangr Note it is an xlvalue only if it is implicitly movable entity which is true here. Also, the answer does point out that the *"expression were an rvalue expression"*. I will update the answer asap with the details from the newer standard.

Comment: @DanielLangr Updated the answer in the dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When returning a local variable by value the compiler will prefer to move it over doing a copy if it can't do *named* return value optimization, as in your case since you've turned NRVO (named return value optimization) off - URVO (or unnamed RVO) can't be turned off, at least not while in a strict conformance mode.

> the copy construtor should be called to initialize the temporary object

There is no temporary object that I can see. The output I get from g++, clang++ and icx in C++17 mode with `-fno-elide-constructors` has only one move:

```
c'tor
before return ReturnObj
move c'tor
d'tor
end main
d'tor
```

---

In the link you showed, they compile in C++11 mode:

```bash
clang++ -std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors
```

Mandatory URVO wasn't a thing until C++17. In C++11 and 14 both URVO and NRVO is *allowed* but not mandatory. You can turn off both RVO versions in C++11 and 14 with `-fno-elide-constructors`, but in C++17 URVO is mandatory and can't be turned off while NRVO can be.

Comment: The second move is from the temporary object. In old days when RVO is not enforced, when function return, a temp obj actually is created. I switched RVO off to observe this. The second move is the same as I expected. The only thing I didn't expect is the line of the first move. I guess the local variable snit is an xvalue, which is also a soon-to-destroyed lvalue, or rvalue. I'm not sure about this.

Comment: @Wason I didn't pay attention to your output so I've updated it with the output I see. How did you _"switched RVO off"_? `-fno-elide-constructors` doesn't do that.

Comment: @Wason I think I figured out where you got the second move from and updated the answer again.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You can disable RVO before C++17: https://godbolt.org/z/63r19WK8W.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am not sure whether the term RVO has some established definition. But in my opinion, it existed even before C++17: https://godbolt.org/z/f5ahTb5dc. Without `-fno-elide-constructors`, both move constructor calls are elided, which I consider to be RVO.

Comment: @DanielLangr The answer I've given separates languages before C++17  and those beginning with C++17 - and the question is about C++17, which is why that's my focus at the start.